# Enable conversion between 64 bit integer types

Tags: c++, linux, clang, int64

Trying to port some Windows C++ code to Linux + clang.

Here’s a function:

```
inline __m256i XM_CALLCONV maskload_epi64( const int64_t *mem_addr, __m256i mask )
{
    return _mm256_maskload_epi64( mem_addr, mask );
}
```

Here’s a compiler output:

```
no matching function for call to '_mm256_maskload_epi64'
    return _mm256_maskload_epi64( mem_addr, mask );
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/clang/4.0.0/include/avx2intrin.h:989:1: note: candidate function
      not viable: no known conversion from 'const int64_t *'
      (aka 'const long *') to 'const long long *' for 1st argument
_mm256_maskload_epi64(long long const *__X, __m256i __M)
```

Is there a compiler switch to make it cast between different 64 bit built-in types without errors?

Comment: A `const long *` and a `const long long *` are fundamentally different types. What magic would you have the compiler perform?

Comment: The error message suggests you're asking the wrong question: it seems `int64_t` is equivalent to `long` (i.e. `long` is 64-bits) but that the first argument of `_mm256_maskload_epi64()` is a pointer to `long long *` with `long long` bigger than a `long` on your target system. You would be better off reading documentation for `_mm256_maskload_epi64()` to work out what the first argument really is (e.g. is it 128 bit or 256 bits?). Forcing the code to compile  without such understanding would probably simply shift the problem to a runtime error.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I’m building for AMD64, they have same sizeof() 8 and they are both integers. What do you mean “fundamentally different”?

Comment: @Peter No, both are 64 bit, here's the doc: https://software.intel.com/en-us/cpp-compiler-18.0-developer-guide-and-reference-mm-maskload-epi32-64-mm256-maskload-epi32-64 BTW my system has a 64 bit Xeon CPU, it doesn't support scalar integer types larger than 64 bits.

Comment: In that case, you don't need a compiler switch. Simply use `reinterpret_cast<const long long *>(mem_addr)` as the first argument. However, this may cause the code to fail (either with a compiler diagnostic or a runtime error) if your compiler is updated in future so `long` and `long long` types have different sizes than at present. By "fundamentally different", Jesper means that `long *` and `long long *` are incompatible types according to the standard (e.g. compilers must diagnose an implicit conversion from one to the other) even on implementations with `long` and `long long` the same size.

Comment: @Peter That C++ code is generated automatically from something else. I can add casts in that generator but it’s relatively hard, and I’ll need to support all of them like _mm256_maskload_epi64, _mm_maskstore_epi64, _mm_stream_si64, _mm_set1_epi64x, and lots more. Both Intel and AMD think all these instructions handle 64-bit integers. However, clang developers decided to use “long long” type instead of the more standard int64_t, AND made them incompatible. VC++ has `typedef long long int64_t;` in their <stdint.h> so it works fine on Windows.

Comment: @Soonts - the problem is presumably that clang works across multiple systems, and support of `int64_t` is optional (i.e. they can't simply assume it is supported on any particular target system, even if it happens to be in VC++).   In any event, although it will take you more work up-front now, it is probably better for the long run to update your "generator".     That way, if system specifications (or clang for that matter) change in future, you'll be able to update the generator to suit, rather than relying on compiler options that don't exist now, and are not guaranteed to exist in future.

Comment: @Peter “clang works across multiple systems” right, but these SSE and AVX intrinsics don’t, clang only supports them on Intel 32 and AMD64 platforms. “if system specifications (or clang for that matter) change in future” This will never happen. `movnti` SSE2 instruction (= `_mm_stream_si64` intrinsic) will never start writing some other count of bits, this would break almost 100% of the existing software.

Comment: @Peter At the end I did what you said here, updated the generator. The reason for that, I really like `<stdint.h>` and I didn’t want to introduce these `long long`s in the API. Here’s that commit, BTW: https://github.com/Const-me/IntelIntrinsics/commit/076b950f34dfcfc630df251309ac3aa839fd6f76 As you see, the generator has updated about ~50 C++ functions.